# transferring files from vmware ubuntu to windows ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, file-transfer

I just downloaded Ubuntu for Windows and want to start programming in this environment. Unfortunately, all the files and packages needed are on my VMWare Ubuntu. I found instructions to save all my configs and packages to move to another machine, but how do I move that folder to my Ubuntu on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enable folder sharing. The guide https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_running9.html is old (sorry I clicked on the first google hit) so search for a newer one. Also if your "Ubuntus" are running in GUI folder you could just send them to the cloud and pull it back down from the other machine.

Comment: I already copied the files onto a flash drive and moved them to my windows machine. That's not the issue. The problem is this Ubuntu for Windows is command line only, so I don't have a GUI. I'm not sure if there's a place on the Windows machine for this subsystem to move the files.

Comment: The easiest way for this is then to install an ext filesystem reader for windows and copy the files via GUI, alternatively mount the usb  in Ubuntu like this :https://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal

Comment: ah thank you very much, just what i needed